# X-Frame-Options ignored in Chrome / Firefox. IE works

Tags: 2013, iis, iframe, page-viewer-web-part, x-frame

I have a simple PageViewer Webpart loading mysites. This displays in an iFrame within IE but doesn't display in Chrome or Firefox.

I have tried adding the following to my MasterPage:

```
<meta name="X-FRAME-OPTIONS" content="ALLOW-FROM" />
<!--SPM:<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />-->
```

I have also tried adding the following in IIS (on both mysites and host site collection):

```
X-Frame-Options = SAMEORIGIN
X-Frame-Options = ALLOWALL
```

None of which work in Chrome or Firefox. I am getting this error in Chrome:

> Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values
>   ('SAMEORIGIN, ALLOWALL') encountered when loading
>   'htp://siteURL:2000'. Falling back to 'DENY'.

Shouldn't it work with SAMEORIGIN if the 2 site collections are on the same server / web application, just a different port? Where can I impact the original setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had to enable this at the Master page level (of the source trying to load within the iFrame):

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" ></WebPartPages:AllowFraming>
```

Hope this helps someone.